# Get WMI properties

Tags: c#, usb, wmi, wmi-query

I am quite novice in c# but unfortunately have to discover usb ports VIDs and PIDs.

```
ObjectQuery objectQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE ConfigManagerErrorCode = 0");
ManagementObjectSearcher comPortSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(connectionScope, objectQuery);

using (comPortSearcher)
{
    string caption = null;
    foreach (ManagementObject obj in comPortSearcher.Get())
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            object captionObj = obj["Caption"];
            // Rest of code
        }
    }
}
```

I actually can't understand whre this key `"Caption"` comes from. How can I know what else keys are hidden in this object? It is very unclear for me. 
How can I get the list of other of such a `"Keys"`

Comment: Use the debugger to inspect the `obj` variable. You should be able to drill into its properties.

Comment: I have but no success unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code accesses by WMI different properties. Specifically `Win32_PnPEntity` class *represents the properties of a Plug and Play device*.

See more on MSDN about [Win32_PnPEntity class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394353(v=vs.85).aspx) and it's properties:

```
[Dynamic, Provider("CIMWin32"), UUID("{FE28FD98-C875-11d2-B352-00104BC97924}"), AMENDMENT]
class Win32_PnPEntity : CIM_LogicalDevice
{
  uint16   Availability;
  string   Caption;
  string   ClassGuid;
  string   CompatibleID[];
  uint32   ConfigManagerErrorCode;
  /* Rest of properties... */
};
```

The [`ManagementObjectSearcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher(v=vs.110).aspx) is one way to [retrieve information of a WMI Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393244(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much. It has sorted my problem. I will accept it as the answer in 7 minutes (quite interesting why I cant do it earlier)

Comment: @PeterJ - You are welcome :) and thanks for going to accept the answer :)  As for the time period: [Why can't I accept an answer in the first 15 minutes after asking the question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250132/6400526) ;)